# asp.net core mvc bug: only the first two of my beginform helpers work on this view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

The goal of my code is that a user of the website should be able to enter a name into a box on the page and a URL to a thumbnail image and populate that box with the name and the image. It currently works for the first two boxes. I can't get it to work for boxes three or four, as they simply assign the same boxId that the first two boxes do. I'm completely stuck here.

Does anyone have any feedback on why I can't populate the player 3 or player 4 boxes with a character name and image like I can with the first two? The code looks the same for all four Html helper forms, do I have a syntax error somewhere? Am I running into some limitation about the number of forms I can have on one view?

Debugging strategies or alternate strategies to accomplish the same thing are also welcome.

[Bug in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2cCH.gif)

```
//Controller

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VirtualDmScreen.Models;

namespace VirtualDmScreen.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly VirtualDmScreenContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, VirtualDmScreenContext db)
        {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _db = db;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<DmTrackSelection> tracks = _db.DmTrackSelections.ToList();
            ViewBag.DmTrackSelectionId = new SelectList(_db.DmTrackSelections, "DmTrackSelectionId", "TrackName");
            ViewBag.DmImgSelectionId = new SelectList(_db.DmImgSelections, "DmImgSelectionId", "ImgName");
            
            var dmSelections = _db.DmChoices.FirstOrDefault(selection => selection.DmChoiceId == 1);
            DmTrackSelection dmTrackSelection = dmSelections.DmTrackSelection;
            DmImgSelection dmImgSelection = dmSelections.DmImgSelection;
            ViewBag.SelectedTrack = dmTrackSelection;
            ViewBag.SelectedImg = dmImgSelection;
            
            var userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            Character model = currentUser.Character;
            Console.WriteLine("************************************" + currentUser.Character.Name + currentUser.Character.BoxId);
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int dmTrackSelectionId, int dmImgSelectionId)
        {
            DmChoice newDmChoice = new DmChoice {DmChoiceId = 1, DmTrackSelectionId = dmTrackSelectionId, DmImgSelectionId = dmImgSelectionId};
            _db.Entry(newDmChoice).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditCharacter(Character character, int boxId)
            {
        //    var userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        //     var thisCharacter = _db.Characters.FirstOrDefault(Character => Character.ApplicationUserId == userId);
            character.BoxId = boxId;
            Console.WriteLine(boxId);
            _db.Entry(character).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

//Index.cshtml

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles.css" />
<h1>Welcome to Virtual Dm Screen</h1>
<body style="background-image: url('@ViewBag.SelectedImg.ImgPath');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;background-size: 100% 100%;">
<iframe src='https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/@ViewBag.SelectedTrack.SpotifyTrack' width="100%" height="80" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

@using VirtualDmScreen.Models
@model VirtualDmScreen.Models.Character

@if (@User.IsInRole("DM"))
{   
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("DmTrackSelectionId")
        @Html.DropDownList("DmImgSelectionId")

        <input type="submit" value="Input Selections">

    }
}
else
{
    <p>Your Screen</p>
}
  <hr>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3" id="chatbox">
                <h5>Chat Box</h5>
                <p>Some text here!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3" id="dicebox">
                <h5>Dice Box</h5>
                <p>Some text here!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
        @* Empty Box *@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2" id="emptyBox">
                  <p>@Html.ActionLink("Register/Login", "Index", "Account", null, new { id="OT", style = "color:black;text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white, 1px -1px 0 white, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white;" })</p>
                  <p>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @* Player One *@
        <div class="col-3">
            <h5>Player One</h5>
                @if(@Model.BoxId == 1)
                { 
                    @Model.Name
                    <br>
                    <img src="@Model.ImageUrl">
                } 
                else
                { 
                    @Html.BeginForm("EditCharacter","Home", new {boxId = 1})
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CharacterId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                        <br>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                    }
                 };             
            
        </div>
        @* Player Two *@
        <div class="col-3" id="playerTwo">
            <h5>Player Two</h5>
            @if(@Model.BoxId == 2)
            { 
                @Model.Name
                <br>
                <img src="@Model.ImageUrl">
            } 
            else
            { 
                @Html.BeginForm("EditCharacter","Home", new {boxId = 2})
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CharacterId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    <br>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                }
            }
        </div>
        @* Player Three *@
        <div class="col-3" id="playerThree">
            <h5>Player Three</h5>
            @if(@Model.BoxId == 3)
            { 
                @Model.Name
                <br>
                <img src="@Model.ImageUrl">
            } 
            else
            { 
                @Html.BeginForm("EditCharacter","Home", new {boxId = 3})
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CharacterId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    <br>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                }
            }
        </div>
        @* Player Four *@
        <div class="col-3" id="playerFour">
            <h5>Player Four</h5>
            @if(@Model.BoxId == 4)
            { 
                @Model.Name
                <br>
                <img src="@Model.ImageUrl">
            } 
            else
            { 
                @Html.BeginForm("EditCharacter","Home", new {boxId = 4})
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CharacterId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    <br>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd start by checking F12 console tab for errors.  Then take the rendered HTML and run it through an HTML validator

Comment: I did a quick search but can't find an HTML validator that recognizes the razor code.

Comment: That's why I suggested that you use the *rendered* HTML -- so grab the HTML from F12 Elements tab.

Comment: Oh, gotcha, how do you copy the code from the elements tab to your clipboard?

Comment: Hmmm... good question.  It's probably easier to right click on the page and select View Source and then copy that

Comment: Ok, so one of the errors it's returning is that I have a second form start tag, but the first form tag isn't closed, and nested forms aren't allowed, which seems like it would be consistent with the bug I'm seeing, but my BeginForm html helpers look like they are closed properly with curly braces...

Comment: Can you edit your question and add in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Ok, I've actually got it figured out, the hint to use the rendered HTML in a validator was really great because it revealed to me that I was trying to nest forms, so I looked at my HTML helper syntax. The thing that I was missing was I needed to surround Html.BeginForm() with @using() in order for the forms to close correctly. The site is now functioning as expected. Thanks @devlin

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?